# where to place IE conditional statements for a better organization?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, structure, conditional-statements

I'm using the following IE compatibility for IE8 and IE9. Fine it works perfectly, but as you can see pretty long right?

So I would like to insert it in a file as an external link or any other solution. Where can you place this code so it does not annoy you on the header?

```
<!-- IE compatibility -->
            <!--[if lt IE 8]>
       <script>
          document.createElement('header');
          document.createElement('nav');
          document.createElement('section');
          document.createElement('article');
          document.createElement('aside');
          document.createElement('footer');
       </script>
    <![endif]-->

            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script>
          document.createElement('header');
          document.createElement('nav');
          document.createElement('section');
          document.createElement('article');
          document.createElement('aside');
          document.createElement('footer');
       </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using the second block? Anything that's less than IE8 is also less than IE9.

Comment: @BoltClock I dont undertand what you mean, could you explain? .. first tie I use the IE conditionals.

Comment: @BoltClock I think you mean that the code is influencing IE9 and less right? SO I dont need to have the other code for IE8 and less. Could you or others let me know how to store the IE correctly or ina better way? I find it so aggresive beside the head...

Comment: Yes, that's what `lt IE 9` means, so you don't need the first block.

Comment: @BoltClock Any hint to how to place this as for example an external link? Therefore I dont have that long code on the header. Thanks!